# Print preview blank when using session variables for data. Local variables work fine

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, printing

Im working on a web based, mobile application for my technicians to print out invoices in the field.

The application is programmed mostly in php/html/css and javascript.

The printing is done with a canon pixma i110 connected via wifi to a 4g tablet. When the technician tries to print, he is presented with a blank screen if the variables aren't defined locally. I've echoed the session variables in question and they have the expected values.

```
$var1 = $_SESSION['var1'];
//$var1 = "value1";
$var2 = $_SESSION['var2'];
//$var2 = "value2"

mysql_connect("host","user","pass")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("table")or die("cannot select DB");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT `field1`,`field2` FROM mytable WHERE `fieldx` = '$var1' AND `fieldz` = '$var2' ORDER BY `id` ASC") or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $info1=$row["invoice_name"];
        $info2=$row["print_copy"];
    }
echo $info2;
```

When the mysql query is performed as is above, the print page yields nothing. When I use the local defined variables, the print page gives me the expected result.

I've been at this for a while now, i've done plenty of searches on this site as well as others, but have yet to find a solution. I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate question.

Thanks for your help.

*Edit: It appears to me that the session variables are not available to the browser during conversion to print. How can I get around this?*

Comment: have you session_start() before? check if session exist via if(!isset($_SESSION['var1'])) { die('session does not exist'); }

Comment: Yes, as it says above, I have echoed the sessions, and they have the correct data. 
Of course i have session_start(); at the top of the page :)

Comment: ok so $var1 have correct data? second dump your sql_query if is correct

Comment: I'm thinking it has something to do with session data not being available when the browser converts the file for printing. I don't know a way around it....

Comment: use var_dump() not echo for dumping variables

Comment: Yes, $var1 and $var2 both have the correct data... will do.

Comment: you print whole data to html page and then make print page from browser?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what im doing.

Comment: and you see correct data printed in browser and then you want them print out you get blank page?

Comment: and whats print view? show page data?

Comment: print view is also blank

Comment: hm .. is possible see live version?

Comment: Its not necessary, i've posted everything relevant to this problem.

Comment: The print page works when $var1, $var2 are defined locally. When they are defined by the session vars, the print page shows nothing. Pretty cut & dry.

Comment: try print out only session variables and completed query if they are available in print view without nothing more

Comment: Session vars show nothing in print view

Comment: I believe there's something you're forgetting to mention. A quick test shows that a session variable visible on the screen is still visible in the print preview. So there must be something else at play in your situation. Are you sure the session has not been closed before you're trying to print?

Comment: No, im not forgetting anything, I think you may have overlooked the tablet part. The printing is done from a tablet in the field. Not a computer in an office.

Comment: When I try to print from my office computer, it works just fine whether the variables are local or session vars. However, when trying to print from the tablet, only the local variables show in print/print preview.

Comment: What kind of tablet is it exactly? What browser?

Comment: Its an LG G Pad 7, We're using the latest chrome browser. Printing is done using the PrinterShare application from playstore.

Comment: Got around it by using text files to store the temp data, but i'd still like to be able to accomplish this with only session and cookies, so if someone ever finds out what causes this, please post here.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Include favicon in headers. I feel like a moron.